# How to write connectstring to read excel with Oledb with readonly mode in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

```
    string _filePath = @"C:\Users\szhao\Downloads\USER_UploadCSV.xlsx";
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(_filePath);
    string _connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Mode=Read;Data Source=" + _filePath + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\"";
    if (fi.Extension.Equals(".xlsx") || fi.Extension.Equals(".xls"))
    {
        // For Excel 2007 File  Format
        _connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Data Source=" + _filePath + " ;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"";
    }
    OleDbConnection _conn = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString);
    _conn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connect!");
```

The `Mode=Read` in connectionstring should indicate this is readonly mode, that will allow multi-application read single excel without write.
But it throw exception in `_conn.Open();`, so I just thought might be my connection string is wrong?

Following is exception message

```
Exception Message:
External table is not in the expected format.

Stack Trace:
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at TIDEAPI.BLL.AExcelFile..ctor(TestAdministration pTestAdministration, String pFilePath, UploadFileSpecification pUploadFileSpecification) in c:\Projects\PreProcessing\TIDE\Online\TIDEAPI\BLL\FileUpload\Abstraction\AExcelFile.cs:line 41
   at TIDEAPI.BLL.ExcelFile..ctor(TestAdministration pTestAdministration, String pFilePath, UploadFileSpecification pUploadFileSpecification) in c:\Projects\PreProcessing\TIDE\Online\TIDEAPI\BLL\FileUpload\ExcelFile.cs:line 14
   at TIDEAPI.BLL.AcceptableFileFactory.GetAcceptableFile(TestAdministration pTestAdministration, String pFilePath, UploadFileSpecification pUploadFileSpecification) in c:\Projects\PreProcessing\TIDE\Online\TIDEAPI\BLL\FileUpload\AcceptableFileFactory.cs:line 22
   at TIDEAPI.BLL.AFileProcessor..ctor(Int64 pTestAdministartionKey, String pFilePath, UploadFileSpecification pUploadFileSpecification, FrequencyDistributionLogger fdLogger, DataExchangeErrorLogger errorLogger, IDictionary`2 dataExchangeProperties) in c:\Projects\PreProcessing\TIDE\Online\TIDEAPI\BLL\FileUpload\Abstraction\AFileProcessor.cs:line 108
   at TIDEAPI.BLL.UserFileProcessor..ctor(Int64 pTestAdministrationKey, String pTideFile, UploadFileSpecification pUploadFileSpecification, FrequencyDistributionLogger fdLogger, DataExchangeErrorLogger errorLogger, IDictionary`2 dataExchangeProperties) in c:\Projects\PreProcessing\TIDE\Online\TIDEAPI\BLL\FileUpload\UserFileProcessor.cs:line 32
   at TIDEAPI.BLL.FileProcessorFactory.GetFileProcessor(Int64 pTestAdministrationKey, String pFilePath, UploadFileSpecification pUploadFileSpecification, FrequencyDistributionLogger fdLogger, DataExchangeErrorLogger errorLogger, FileProcessorTypes pFileProcessorType, IDictionary`2 dataExchangeProperties) in c:\Projects\PreProcessing\TIDE\Online\TIDEAPI\BLL\FileUpload\FileProcessorFactory.cs:line 42
   at PreIdService.PreIdFile.Load(Object pWorkerThreadParameters) in c:\Projects\PreProcessing\TIDE\Online\Tools\TideBatchUploadService\PreIdFile.cs:line 62
```

If I remove the Mode=Read, it will not allow multi Application to read, but single user will works.

Comment: if you remove `Mode=Read` does it work properly?

Comment: If I remove the Mode=Read, it will not allow multi Application to read, but single user will works.

Comment: Try adding `ReadOnly=True` in addition to `Mode=Read`.

Comment: www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 1):

ConnectionString for xls and xlsx are different.

```
if (fi.Extension.Equals(".xls"))
{
   _connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + 
       _filePath + " ;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"";
}
else if (fi.Extension.Equals(".xlsx"))
{
   _connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
       _filePath + " ;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"";
}
```